# Setting Decimal Datatype in Sequel Pro

Tags: sequelpro

I am new to Sequel Pro.

I am trying to import a csv file that has longitude and latitude coordinates, but when the "CSV Import Field Mapping" window shows up, DECIMAL/FLOAT/DOUBLE is not one of the datatypes I can choose in the pulldown menu.  The only numeric datatypes I see are INT and BIGINT.

How do I import a file that has decimal numbers and set it as such in Sequel Pro?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with Sequel Pro 1.1.2. This isn't an ideal solution, but I imported my CSV files with TablePlus, which did the job adequately.

It's a free download. ‍♂

To reproduce the problem, click the "Export Data" link on [this baseball website](https://www.fangraphs.com/leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=bat&lg=all&qual=y&type=1&season=2018&month=0&season1=2018&ind=0&team=0&rost=0&age=0&filter=&players=0). Then import the downloaded CSV in Sequel Pro, selecting the option to create a new table. You'll (presumably) get the result posted in the images linked below, where DECIMAL/FLOAT/DOUBLE is not offered as an option for decimal fields in the downloaded data.

[image: Baseball data to import]

[image: Sequel Pro does not offer DECIMAL/FLOAT/DOUBLE for OBP field, among others]